# Match typical password patterns in a text

Tags: regex

I need a Regex to search in text files for typical password patterns, such as

A word that contains lower case, upper case letters, and digits, and is 6-30 characters long in an arbitrary text, such as the following.

```
This is some sample text containing an email address of michael.knight@knightrider2000.com 
and some cryptic secret like am2Nals2kdP5 and even more text.
```

I'd like to match am2Nals2kdP5, but nothing else in that example.

I tried `\s[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,30}\s`, but this matches other word like `containing`, too. I understand that this is, because `[...]` matches to any of the characters, instead of all of them. However I cannot find the proper syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: `[…]` matches *any* of the enclosed characters, not *all*.

Comment: Thanks, I can understand why `[...]` is not working. I adjusted my initial post accordingly. But how does this lead me to a solution do my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex `\s[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,30}\s` would match any whitespace character `\s`, any in these ranges `[a-zA-Z0-9]` with `{6,30}` for the repetition followed by any whitespace character `\s`.

This would match for example `aaaaaa` or `1Aa2bbzzzzzzz`

You could use [positive lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=` to assert that what follows contains a lowercase character, an uppercase character and a digit.

For example:

[`(?=[A-Z\d]*[a-z])(?=[a-z\d]*[A-Z])(?=[a-zA-Z]*[\d])[a-zA-Z\d]{6,30}`](https://regex101.com/r/uz2h9A/1/)

**Note** that this does not take the whitespaces before and after into account.

To do this, you [could add](https://regex101.com/r/bFCxUp/1/) a positive lookbehind `(?<=^|\s)` at the beginning to assert that what is before is the beginning of the string or any whitespace character  and add a positive lookahead `(?=$|\s)` to assert that what follows is the end of the string or any whitespace character.

Comment: Or word boundaries?

Comment: A wordboundary would for example also match between # and f

Comment: Right. I didn't thought about it as special characters wasn't mentionned. Nice shot!

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I've tried working wiht lookarounds, but couldn't figure the right way.